# I don't understand what my professor is telling me in this statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, numerical-methods

“Commonly in Mathematics we need to solve equations of the form f(x) = 0, for x where f :I→R is a real valued function defined on a subset I ⊆ R.”

I understand the first part of the statement, yes there are equations of the form f(x) = 0, some not simple to solve.  I understand that the domain can be in the set of imaginary numbers and the range can be in the set of real numbers or at least I think I understand that.

The part I don’t get is I ⊆ R, the imaginary numbers are not a subset of the real numbers. I know irrational nubmers set is denoted Q.

I’m confused about the argument my professor is making.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: $I$ is likely not the set of imaginary numbers, but some arbitrary subset of $\Bbb R$. (Usually complex numbers would be alluded to by the set $\Bbb C$.)

Comment: Quite.  I would further infer that $I$ here likely stands in reference to an *interval*.  It may of course be more than an interval, but having intervals as domains are of particular interest with how continuity is defined.

Comment: One more correction: $\mathbb Q$ denotes the *rational* numbers, not the irrational numbers. I don't know of a standard notation for the imaginary numbers. An unambiguous notation would be $i\mathbb R$ (the set of numbers of the form $ix$ where $x$ is real).

Answer (score 6):

$I$ here does not denote the imaginary numbers. It just denotes some subset of the real numbers, which is what "$I \subseteq R$" is communicating.

Edit for more detail: As far as I know, there is no notation for the set of purely imaginary numbers besides maybe $i \mathbb{R}$. The usual notation for the set of complex numbers is $\mathbb{C}$. In contexts similar to that of your question, $I$ is often used to denote an interval of the real line, but given the exact wording of your question I would not immediately assume that they are implying $I$ is an interval.

Comment: Specifically, $I$ stands for "interval".

Answer (score 4):

Many theorems (and related algorithms) about existence of roots $f(x)=0$ assume the domain $I$ for $f:I\to \mathbb R$ to be a finite *interval* $I=[a,b]$.

For example, the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that for *continuous* such function $f$ with $f(a)f(b) < 0$ (opposite signs for $f$ at the endpoints), there exists a point $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

The Bisection Algorithm for root finding assumes much the same conditions.